# DisplayMonitor to Forms.Screen mapping

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I want to diplay a dropdown to the user which displays the device name (like in the Windows resolution settings) besides each entry. I can do this via `Windows.Devices.Display.DisplayMonitor` and related APIs like so:

```cs
private async Task CollectMonitors() {
    var displays = await  DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DisplayMonitor.GetDeviceSelector());
    List<DisplayMonitor> displayMonitors = new List<DisplayMonitor>();

    foreach (var display in displays)
    {
        displayMonitors.Add(await DisplayMonitor.FromInterfaceIdAsync(display.Id));
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Now, `displayMonitors` contains all monitors, and each of those has a `DisplayName` property, which is exactly what the Windows screen resolution settings show (e.g. `"DELL P2422H"`), as well as a `DeviceId` (e.g. `\\?\DISPLAY#DELA1C5#4&b8ecaec&0&UID24627#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}`) which is unique per device.

It **doesn't** tell me the following very important information, which I need in order to actually use the selected screen to put a WPF window on it:

- Working area
- Whether it's the primary monitor

This info is provided by `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens`. My issue with this API is that this does **not** include the `DisplayName` (like `"DELL P2422H"`) which I need for the display to the user.

My questions are now:

1. Can I somehow map a `DisplayMonitor` to a `Forms.Screen`? This would be the simplest solution. I cannot find any identifier which is unique per monitor, and shared by both of these APIs/results. There is no documentation about whether the order of screens in `Forms.Screen.AllScreens` somehow relates to the order returned by enumerating `DisplayMonitors` via `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync`, so probably not(?).
2. If that doesn't work, is there a way to obtain the extents of the working area from the `DisplayMonitor`, or from an EDID, or from any other information provided by the `DisplayMonitor` API, or from any related APIs that I could use here?

Relevant links:

- `DisplayMonitor` API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.displaymonitor
- `Forms.Screen` API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen

This is ****NOT**** answered by related questions which do either a) not mention the display name or b) do not mention the working area / spawning a WPF window on the monitor.

Answer (score 3):

It's not super easy to link WinRT classes with GDI/GDI+ classes as WinRT classes don't expose GDI's device name such as `\\.\DISPLAY1` which is exposed by Winforms (and can be used from WPF too).

So what you can do is use [Connecting and Configuring Displays (CCD) Win32 APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/connecting-and-configuring-displays) (BTW this is what WinRT classes use to get monitor's display name, etc. you can also use them to determine if HDR is on/off [Windows API to get whether HDR(High Dynamic Range) is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66155083/windows-api-to-get-whether-hdrhigh-dynamic-range-is-active)) to determine the GDI device name from an adapter id:

```
public static string GetGdiDeviceName(int adapterIdHigh, uint adapterIdLow, uint sourceId)
{
    var info = new DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME();
    const int DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME = 1;
    info.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME;
    info.header.size = Marshal.SizeOf<DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME>();
    info.header.adapterIdHigh = adapterIdHigh;
    info.header.adapterIdLow = adapterIdLow;
    info.header.id = sourceId;
    var err = DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref info);
    if (err != 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(err);

    return info.viewGdiDeviceName;
}

// to build this, use more CCD APIs definitions from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66160049/403671
public static uint GetSourceId(uint targetId)
{
    var err = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, out var pathCount, out var modeCount);
    if (err != 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(err);

    var paths = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[pathCount];
    var modes = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[modeCount];
    err = QueryDisplayConfig(QDC.QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, ref pathCount, paths, ref modeCount, modes, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (err != 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(err);

    return paths.First(p => p.targetInfo.id == targetId).sourceInfo.id;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private struct DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME
{
    public DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER header;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string viewGdiDeviceName;

    public override string ToString() => viewGdiDeviceName;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER
{
    public int type;
    public int size;
    public uint adapterIdLow;
    public int adapterIdHigh;
    public uint id;
}

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern int DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo(ref DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME requestPacket);
```

But this needs a "SourceId", which you can get from WinRT using the [IDisplayPathInterop interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windows.devices.display.core.interop/nn-windows-devices-display-core-interop-idisplaypathinterop) (or, for older Windows versions that wouldn't support it, using CCD API again, see `GetSourceId` method):

```
// seems available at least Windows 10, Version 21H1 (kernel32.dll version 6.2.19043.928) 
[ComImport, Guid("A6BA4205-E59E-4E71-B25B-4E436D21EE3D"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDisplayPathInterop
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int CreateSourcePresentationHandle(out IntPtr value);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSourceId(out uint sourceId);
}
```

And now you can use all this to dump a maximum number of information for example this C# console app:

```
static void Main()
{
    using (var mgr = DisplayManager.Create(DisplayManagerOptions.None))
    {
        var state = mgr.TryReadCurrentStateForAllTargets().State;
        foreach (var view in state.Views)
        {
            foreach (var path in view.Paths)
            {
                var monitor = path.Target.TryGetMonitor();
                if (monitor != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(monitor.DisplayName);
                    uint sourceId;
                    if ((object)path is IDisplayPathInterop ip)
                    {
                        ip.GetSourceId(out sourceId);
                    }
                    else // handle older Windows versions
                    {
                        sourceId = GetSourceId(path.Target.AdapterRelativeId);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" GDI Name      : " + gdiDeviceName);

                    // use gdiDeviceName to correlate with other APIs such as Screen from Winforms

                    var screen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => s.DeviceName == gdiDeviceName);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Is Primary    : " + screen.Primary);
                    Console.WriteLine(" Working Area  : " + screen.WorkingArea);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will output something like this (2 monitors):

```
DELL U2715H
 GDI Name      : \\.\DISPLAY1
 Is Primary    : False
 Working Area  : {X=2560,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1392}

C27HG7x
 GDI Name      : \\.\DISPLAY2
 Is Primary    : True
 Working Area  : {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1392}
```

Comment: A great answer. But as far as I tested this code in WPF app specifying `net8.0-windows10.0.20348.0` as target framework moniker (Windows 10 SDK 10.0.20348.0 is installed) on Windows 11, "ip" is always null.

Comment: @emoacht - Beyond SDK and compilation setup, it requires Windows 10 Build 20348 at runtime, do you have tested on this Windows version or higher?

Comment: Actually, I've tested on a Windows 10, Version 21H1 (kernel32.dll version 6.2.19043.928) and it works too

Comment: @emoacht Or you can use [QueryDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#examples) to get the source id `path.sourceInfo.id`. Tested.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT - true, I've added graceful handling to the answer for older Windows versions

Comment: @SimonMourier I have not tested on Windows 10 Build 20348. I thought if it only works on Windows 10 build 20348 (Windows Server 2022) but does not on Windows 11, the usefullness of IDisplayPathInterop might be limited.

Comment: @emoacht [`QueryDisplayConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#requirements) is useful constantly.

Comment: @emoacht IDisplayPathInterop works on all Windows since 21H1

Comment: @SimonMourier I have mostly copied your code and tested on Windows 10 Home 22H2 (10.0.19045.4170) and Windows 11 Home 23H2 (10.0.22635.3350). In both cases, IDisplayPathInterop didn't work. I will appreciate it if you could try the test repo [emoacht/DisplayPathTest](https://github.com/emoacht/DisplayPathTest) and point out the difference from what you have tested.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Yes, I confirmed QueryDisplayConfig works. Thank you.